# JavaScript won't work if placed inside the body of a web page?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I've learned that JavaScript can be place between the *`<head></head>`* or *`<body></body>`* sections, I have been working in a project and it works fine inside the head but not the body section of the page.

examples:

working fine like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Example Page</title>

<script>
function yetAnotherAlert(textToAlert) {
  alert(textToAlert);
}

yetAnotherAlert("Hello World");
```

And is not working this way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

<title>Example Page</title>



</head>

<body>
 <script>
    function yetAnotherAlert(textToAlert) {
      alert(textToAlert);
    }

    yetAnotherAlert("Hello World");

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet didn't show you closing the  tag. Double check if you close your script block correctly.

It's also better to specify the type of scripting language too.

```
<script language='javascript'>

....

</script>
```

Comment: It's even better to specify type. `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: Confidential is using the HTML5 doctype. Neither `language` nor `type` are necessary on the script element in his case (for that matter, those attributes aren't necessary in any currently used browsers, regardless of doctype, but `type` is required for XHTML/HTML4 validation)